# How to test for the existence of a function in ngIf

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to hide/show some HTML based on the existence of a function

```
<div ng-if="!!someFunc"> .... </div>
<div ng-if="someFunc !== undefined"> .... </div>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/15065/)

Now the issue is that it doesn't matter if `someFunc` exists or not, it is always shown. Is there some way to make this work or should I create an other (boolean) variable on the scope ?

UPDATE: I've reproduced the issue [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lzgts/458/) this time with angular v1.3.14

Comment: The reproduced issue in your edit is addressed here.  It is fixed in Angular 1.4, and closed as of this January.  https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out now, in Angular 1.0, ng-if does not exist.  If you have to stay with Angular 1.0, try ng-show instead.

EDIT: I wanted to make it clear that while ng-if and ng-show will both achieve what you are looking for in this case, they do behave differently behind the scenes.  In short, when an ng-if expression evaluates to "false", the element will be removed from the DOM.  When an ng-show expression evaluates to false, it simply changes the `display` property of your element.  You can read more in detail [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf).

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  //$scope.test = function () {};
}
```

```html
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Is there a test function: {{!!test}}
  <div ng-show="!!test">CLOSE</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've updated my post, I can now reproduce the issue with a newer version of angular

Comment: @jeanlucaScaljeri This is because when passing functions through scope like in your edit, angular wraps the passed value with another function.  If you console.log(scope.callback) you'll see this.

Comment: @jeanlucaScaljeri It is an issue that has been fixed in Angular 1.4, as stated in the comment I left on the initial question.

Comment: to me it looks like an upvote right ? ( I see, you mean the your post, weird)

Answer (score 1):

It's something wrong with your AngularJs (too old may be).
I've updated it to new(1.3.14) and it works - 
http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/15068/

Without any code change:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) { 
    //$scope.test = function () {};
}
```

Comment: Not sure why, but your fiddle doesn't work. I've updated it too and indeed now it works ([DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lzgts/414/) In the app I'm building I use 1.3.14, so it has to be something else :( Thnx a lot!

Comment: I've updated my example  [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lzgts/458/) It turned out that my code was a bit different after all. So it still doesn't work now with angular v1.3.14. Any suggestion ?

Comment: now it's totally different question. It's your incorrect approach in passing params into the directive

Comment: Why is the approach incorrect. From the docs I get the impression that passing a callback function to a directive is done using the `&`

Comment: just ask another question not to or extent the description of this one. Because my answer was for original one.

Answer (score 1):

You fiddle is using angular 1.0.1 which doesn't even contain `ng-if` (introduced in version 1.1.5). Update the external resource to a newer version or use one of the predefined fiddle frameworks (e.g. angular 1.2).

Answer (score 1):

Both of those attempts work. Something must be wrong with your fiddle. Here's a full example:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
  //$scope.someFunc = function() {};
});
```

```html
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <div>Some func: {{ someFunc ? 'yup' : 'nope' }}</div>
  <div ng-if="!!someFunc">Has some func</div>
  <div ng-if="someFunc !== undefined">Has some func</div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.js"></script>
```